# How do I install Java using another language?

Tags: java, windows, sdk, installation

I'm developing an Android app and I need a Maps API key, so for that I need to get the MD5 of my keystore blablabla.
Turns out my Java is in portuguese and I found out that there's a bug with new Java sdk in portuguese, and I can't get the keytool to work properly, making it impossible to get my api key.

Now I'm trying to uninstall and reinstall Java in English, but Java forces the language to Portuguese and I can't figure out how to change this.
I already changed the system locale just like a tutorial on Java's website told me to and restarted, but nothing changed. I'm now trying to install language packs for Windows to change the whole system language to see if Java understands that I want another language.

I'm using Windows 7 64bits, and Java 1.6.26 (I was using 1.6.26, when I reinstall it will be 29)

**EDIT:** I still coudn't install it in another language other than portuguese, and I also can't find any download link that is not multi-language. Also, I found out my Win7 is Pro, so I can't switch display languages.

Anyone know how to force Java to install in a specific language? Or maybe remove the multi-language aspect of the installer?

Comment: Could you give more details of the sdk Portuguese bug, maybe a link?

Comment: The error message it displays is: "erro de keytool: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown format type at".

Comment: Hi - I don't know if you saw this link, but one possible workaround is to go into Windows Control Panel and change to Windows locale to "US English":  http://www.jroller.com/vagheti/entry/erro_com_keytool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Independent of this problem, do you you want Portugese, or do you want English?  You should absolutely be able to install the language of your preference:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/locale.doc.html

Q: Have you considered doing a "clean install" of Java to a virtual machine?

SUGGESTION:

1) Download vmware player (free): http://www.vmware.com

2) Download an Ubuntu Linux "appliance" (Linux is already pre-installed and pre-configured on the VM for you): http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk

3) Do a "clean install" of the Sun JDK 1.2.xx to the Linux VM

Comment: I installed a Fedora applicance and the keytool worked properly, but I couldn't find the android keystore file whithin the VM. I shared the keystore folder but I don't know where it is on the VM. Any tips?

Comment: Hi - 1) You're not going to have any Android-specific stuff on the VM ... unless you install the Android SDK.  You DON'T have to install Android on the VM, unless you really want to.  2) Here's where you can find the Android keystore files (Windows, Vista/Win7 and Linux): http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html  3) Here's how you can share files/directories between Linux and Windows: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/12/enable-file-sharing-between-windows-xp-and-fedora-14-laughlin/